# Get class from any Dependency injection container

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jboss, ioc-container

I have 2 projects. The first uses Spring 4 and the second uses jBoss 7.

I'm creating a dependency that given a Class name (like "com.foo.Bar") will get the instance from the injection context.

The classes will implement an interface (TransitionRule), so my method would be like:

```
public TransitionRule getRule(String className) {
    //... Magic goes here!
    //get the instance of "className" from any container that the imported project is using.
}
```

Can i do that with only one implementation or i will to create a different implementation to get from Spring and from Jboss context?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bean lookup by name or type in Spring if you have access to the relevant Spring Context.

You can perform a JNDI lookup in a running JBoss container if the object has been registered in JNDI, for example, an EJB is generally registered in JNDI for you.

Both of these methods follow the Lookup or Service-Locator pattern.  These are NOT injections.